# Yii2 REST Example Returns Errant <?PHP Tag

Tags: php, rest, curl, yii2

I've got a simple Yii2 application set up following this [Quick Start Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html). It's so generic and there's no extra code in it.  But for some reason my CURL request returns an extra `<?PHP` tag that's messing it all up.

My Request:

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" "http://backend/users"
```

The Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 28 Jan 2015 15:55:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1j DAV/2 PHP/5.5.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.16
X-Pagination-Total-Count: 1
X-Pagination-Page-Count: 1
X-Pagination-Current-Page: 1
X-Pagination-Per-Page: 20
Link: <http://backend/users?page=1>; rel=self
Content-Length: 178
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

<?php[{"id":1,"email":"chris@email.com","password":"","name":null,"address":null,"address2":null,"city":null,"state":null,"zip":null,"date_created":null,"date_updated":null}]
```

**TL;DR**

My `main.php` config file looks like this:

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'api\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

My `UserController.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\User';
}
```

And my `User.php` model file looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "users".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $address2
 * @property string $city
 * @property string $state
 * @property string $zip
 * @property string $date_created
 * @property string $date_updated
 */
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['date_created', 'date_updated'], 'safe'],
            [['email', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['name', 'address', 'address2'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['city'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['state'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
            [['zip'], 'string', 'max' => 10]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'address2' => 'Address2',
            'city' => 'City',
            'state' => 'State',
            'zip' => 'Zip',
            'date_created' => 'Date Created',
            'date_updated' => 'Date Updated',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to bother everyone...  Turns out in my config/bootstrap.php file my IDE trimmed the whitespace after the opening PHP tag so instead of "<?php " I had "<?php" which was returned as a string instead of parsed as PHP

Answer (score 1):

I'd go ahead and search your project folder for `<php`.

```
$ grep -r '<php' /path/to/app
```

If that doesn't help, you could try modifying your index.php file to find where [headers are sent](http://php.net/headers_sent), but this won't work if headers are sent by the framework before the output begins:

```
if (headers_sent($filename, $linenum)) {
    echo "Headers sent in $filename on line $linenum";
}
```

After following their guide rather quickly, I was able to get this:

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" "http://localhost/users"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 28 Jan 2015 19:47:03 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.14
X-Pagination-Total-Count: 1
X-Pagination-Page-Count: 1
X-Pagination-Current-Page: 1
X-Pagination-Per-Page: 20
Link: <http://localhost/users?page=1>; rel=self
Content-Length: 94
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

[{"id":1,"created":"2015-01-28 00:00:00","modified":"2015-01-28 00:00:00","name":"Test User"}]
```